# Show image before object tag data loads

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

So say I have an object tag such as the following:

```
<object id="figure" data="url">Your browser does not support object tag</object>
```

In what way can I show a loader while the data from the URL is being passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the object tag some css:

```
.objectclass
{
 background-image:url(imageurl.gif);
 background-position:center center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

If your object data doesn't cover up the gif, just change the object tags classname in the data onload event.

Comment: Nice! Doesn't work for what I'm working on but definitely answers the question above

Comment: If you'd like to provide some more details I'd be happy to give it another bash.

Comment: You can't change your vote for a question unless the original article is edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a `<img>` tag inside the `<object>` tag so that during the time it takes to load in the framed URL, or in the event that the load returns a `404` request header, the `<img>` will be displayed instead.